# Showing and hiding contents in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]

There is 4 "READ MORE" button.Clicking on each button shows its content in same div. Clicking twice should hide the content.But clicking on one button and then on next button should show the data of second button.How could I do this?

I tried using javascript,checking if content inside div is empty on button click.if empty show the data and if not  document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML="";

Notification Message:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="READ MORE" onclick="displayNotificationMessage();">
```

Verification Message

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="READ MORE" onclick="displayVerificationMessage();">

 <div class="container" id="display_message"  >

          </div>

<script>
function displayNotificationMessage()
{

var data="abcde";   


    var msg=document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML;

     if(msg!="")
     {

     document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML=""; 
     }
     else
     {


     document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML=data; 
    }
}


function displayVerificationMessage()
{

var data="bbjkhkjhkjlk";        

    var msg=document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML;

         if(msg!="")
     {

     document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML=""; 
     }
     else
     {


     document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML=data; 
    }

}
</script>
```

But clicking on one button and clicking on next button will not show contents. 
How to do this?

Comment: can you please show us what youve tried? this isnt the place to get the code written for you, but we can help you if you go wrong.

Comment: You can use jQuery and fill the div with prefilled hidden div content.

Comment: But Clicking  each button should show different contents in same div. @Kiwi Juicer

Comment: Exactly. So you will have one div that you will fill and show onClick and 3 hidden divs with the content and some id to know which to take"

Answer (score 0):

Say you have, div with all texts div#content. In that div you place 4 divs, with separate texts, alle with class .sub-content and proper data attributes.

```
<div id="content">
 <div class="sub-content" data-id="b1">Some text 1<div>
 <div class="sub-content" data-id="b2">Some text 2<div>
 <div class="sub-content" data-id="b3">Some text 3<div>
 <div class="sub-content" data-id="b4">Some text 4<div>
</div>
```

and

```
<button id="b1">Button1<button>
<button id="b2">Button1<button>
<button id="b3">Button1<button>
<button id="b4">Button1<button>
```

Then it is as simple as.

```
$('button').click( function () {
  if ( $('.sub-content[data-id=' +  $(this).attr("id") + ']').css("display") == "hidden" ) {
    $('.sub-content').hide();
    $('.sub-content[data-id=' +  $(this).attr("id") + ']').show();
  } else {
    $('.sub-content[data-id=' +  $(this).attr("id") + ']').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Here clicking on button1 hide its content,button2 hide button2's content and so on...
But I need to toggle the div( show and hide) on button click like on button1 click should show its contents,again button1 click should hide the contents.Also if i first click button1 and next I click button2, div should show button2's content. By default nothing should be shown on div. - @ziemowit

Comment: This is why, there is an if statement on second line. Also in CSS put .sub-content { display: none; }